# EJS include dinâmico

Tags: node.js, express.js, ejs

Utilizando Express 4 e template engine EJS, me deparei com o seguinte:

Digamos que eu tenha a seguinte estrutura:

```
meu_projeto/
+-- server.js
+-- views/
¦   +-- layout.js
¦   +-- admin/
¦   ¦   +-- index.js
¦   ¦   +-- blog/
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- index.js
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- ...
¦   ¦   +-- configs/
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- index.js
¦   ¦   ¦   +-- ...
```

Neste momento, minha rota está assim:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('layout', { page: 'admin/index.ejs' });
});
```

No arquivo **layout.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Exemplo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <% include(page) %>
    </body>
</html>
```

O arquivo **index.ejs** no diretório **admin** está assim apenas para testar:

```
<h2>ADMIN</h2>
```

Mas quando eu acesso a rota, a página a ser incluída não é renderizada.

[image: Página não renderizada]

Como pode ser visto, não retorna nenhum erro no console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para permitir que o HTML seja processar, deve-se utilizar a tag de saída `<%-`.

```
<%- include(page) %>
```

[image: Página renderizada]

Comment: Maaano.. estava ficando maluco aqui. kkkk Não conseguia gerar um html com esse tamplate. Valeu amigo! Ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Na realidade a nova sintaxe do include é assim:

```
`<%- include('filename.ejs') %>`  antes era assim `<% include('filename.ejs') %>` sem o traço.
```

Eles mudaram ultima atuliozação

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).